# What is the meaning of prefix -y in the following examples?

Tags: poetry, middle-english

These are some exmaples from Choser:

1)He was war of me, how у stood
  Before hym and did of myn hood,
  And had ***ygret*** hym as I best koude.

2)A certein tresor that she thider ladde,
And, sooth to seyn, vitaille greet plentee
They han hire ***yeven***, and clothes eek she hadde...

3)For he was late ***уcome*** from his viage,
And wente for to doon his pilgrymage

I guess the meaning of -y can vary, because in **1)** it seems like it`s just playing a part of "I":

*And had I greeted him as I best could*

And in **2)** it looks like a phonetical construction:

*"y"+e = "gi:"

yeven=given (?)*

But I'm not sure at all about those as well as I'm not sure about the third example (maybe it's pronoun again), the meaning of which I can`t even guess now.

Comment: I'm still struggling with Ye Olde Englishe 'xmaples from Choser'.

Answer (score 2):

A past participle form from Old English ge-:

***[Y-](https://www.peterlang.com/view/9783653030273/9783653030273.00012.xml)*** :

> The prefix ge-, a regular past participle marker in Old English, continued to be attached to the past participle throughout the Middle English period. Over time, however, the attachment of ge-, which weakened to a form spelt y- (or i-), be- came no longer obligatory. The Northern dialects eliminated the prefix, leaving suffixes as the sole markers of the past participle. In the South, y- was still used, but optionally, especially in Late Middle English, with a steady increase in the use of forms lacking prefixal marking.

(www.peterlang.com)